# How do I select only odd rows and put it into next column(column1 to column2)

Tags: excel

Like the title says, I need to take texts in odd numbers of rows (3,5,7,9,11,13,15).
and I need to put it in new column from column1 to column2.

How could I do that...would sort function work for me in this situation...?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column with only odd number. for exaple in column `H1` put `1`, in `H2` put `=H1+2` and autocomplete.
If you have data in column A, in column B you put `=INDEX($A$1:$A$26;H1)` and autocomplete...

 Or Use VBA